# Entity Framework Core 7 - Entity combined with polymorphic JSON Column, is this design currently possible?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to solve a generic domain problem using Entity Framework 7.0 features of JSON Columns, intermixed with more concrete domain entity models & properties, but I am struggling to see if the following is actually possible in the current version of tooling.

[image]

In short, I have a shared service 'Customers' where the majority of my entity properties are common, such as name, address, etcetera - but I have a flexible amount of metadata columns per entity type that I want to be able to use through the DBContext model, and be able to Query the results with standard LINQ queries against strongly typed models.

Looking through the documentation about JSON Columns on MSDN - it appears that creating a mappings for:

```
Customer.OwnsOne->VendorMetadata

Customer.OwnsOne->SalespersonMetadata
```

But this appears to only work one-by-one on an OwnedType model, my problem is I would like to have a single-service be able to handle all of the polymorphism, and be able to load the concrete types, including their metadata sub-types - but I cannot see how to configure this in the DBContext, nor if it is even possible?

For example, I would like to be able to load my domain entities, discriminated by type somehow, and have access to the metadata in a strongly typed object?

I want to avoid having to create multiple table inheritance structures with hard-coded columns for the sub-classes as the metadata properties are variable in nature.

I am planning on allowing these entities to be accessible from a REST API, with some discrimination performed by header/requested content type, to vary the representation of the resource based on the user-agents requirements.

```
IEnumerable<Vendor> _vendors = from _context.Customers.Where(v => v.CustomerType == 'Vendor').ToList();

// Now access Vendor specific strongly typed metadata
Console.WriteLine(_vendors.First().Meta.Scheme);

IEnumerable<Vendor> _salesPersons = from _context.Customers.Where(v => v.CustomerType == 'Salesperson').ToList();

// Now access Salesperson specific strongly typed metadata
Console.WriteLine(_salesPersons.First().Meta.Service);
```

There was a thread on Github about a 'JSON Shared Columns' issue that was never voted highly enough to make it to EF7 or EF 8 - but I am not sure it is quite the same thing, or if there is a workaround as it doesn't seem it is going to be available any time soon?

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/28592

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If the metadata properties are variable in nature, how do you want to have access to them in a strongly typed object? Those two requirements currently don't fit well together in my understanding.

Comment: @JineappleAra - variable in nature per sub-type of customer (which is statically known up-front I should add), as opposed to simply variable in terms of a raw Dictionary<string, string> binding for example. Fully aware I might be thinking about this in the wrong manner, but there's a specific use case for it in the terms of the design I am in mind of attempting.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit further on your use case or what the issue is with defining the owned types for the subclasses?

Is it just that you want the data to share a column (as noted in the issue) or something else? You can have a TPH hierarchy where each sub class has their owned json entity, but they would be mapped to different columns.

Comment: @JineappleAra - I think as you explain in your last point, perhaps that is what I am looking for but didn't realise it?

Comment: @JineappleAra

Basically I am trying to have a unified REST service endpoint to allow the retrieval (and some filtering operations) to be performed on each of the concrete sub types of Vendor, and would like to store the data in the same table to ease the burden of adding too much complexity in the DB Model/Context.

Is there an MSDN/example of the TPH Hierarchy with owned columns?

Thank you, appreciate the feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have each of the subclasses as entity, and define the Metadata owned Type for each. EF Core will use the Table per Hierarchy Convention to add a Discriminator Column to differentiate the types, and a column per Metadata type
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Vendor>().
        OwnsOne(v => v.Meta, x =>
        {
            x.ToJson();
        });

    modelBuilder.Entity<Salesperson>().
        OwnsOne(s => s.Meta, x =>
        {
            x.ToJson();
        });
```

If you don't have a DbSet with the base Customer class, you might also need to add

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
```

to the model building method.

You will have a discriminator column for the type (by convention this will be a string with the type name, but you can also configure it). Each Metadata object will be in a separate JSON column. You can specify the name (As an argument to the ToJson Method), but you cannot the choose the same name currently.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will mark this as the answer, though I did manage to get away with standard EF 7.0 TPH mechanism with base and derived classes without using the JSON column feature for now (sparse columns instead!)